# How do I convert URL parameters to lowercase?

Tags: 8, routes

We have a routing.yml file in Drupal 8 which contains the following lines.

```yaml
testmodule.res:
  path: '/subject/{node}' 
  defaults: 
_controller: '\Drupal\testmodule\Controller\resController::res' 
_title: ''
  requirements: 
_permission: 'access content'
```

Right now. the resulting URL is http://www.example.com/subject/MATHS, where *MATHS* should be in lowercase.

How can we convert the parameter in the URL to lowercase for this URL and globally?

Comment: I dont think there is a way to do it in routing.yml, but you can do that in the code from which you are linking this route. You can use the strtolower() function to convert case of variable even before calling the route

Comment: can we do it in the .theme file with condition?

Comment: yes, you can as you can write php code in theme file.

Comment: Not sure if this is a server question like [Convert and redirect URL in uppercase to lowercase using .htaccess](https://serverfault.com/q/177647/291405) or if this is a PHP question like looking for [strtolower(string)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).